# Accessing parts of values in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Got an assignment to write a program that performs actions on a given dictionary according to an integer of a user input

```
Celebrity = {"first_name": "Mariah", "last_name": "Carey", "birth_date": "27.03.1970", "hobbies": ["sing", "compose", "act"]}
```

If the user input is 2, the program is supposed to print Maria's birth month ("3" - part of the string).
If the user input is 4, the program is supposed to print the last hobby on the list ("act").

I tried:

```
user_input = input ("Please enter a number between 1 and 8: ")

if int(user_input) == 2:
    print(Celebrity["birth_date"[4:5])

if int(user_input) == 4:
    print (Celebrity["hobbies"[2]])
```

Both of these conditions end up giving me KeyErrors, how do I go about accessing only a part of a value?

Comment: dictionary access should be based on key so here birth_date is a key you can not slice it like above,
try something like this
`Celebrity["birth_date"][4:5]`, which should not throw error but I don't think this will give you your desired output, but this should help solve your road block, try to do the logic part yourself

Comment: It actually did give the desired output, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is `Celebrity["birthdate"[4:5])` which create error. change it with `Celebrity["birth_date"][4:5]`. and `Celebrity['hobbies[2]']` also create error change it with `Celebrity["hobbies"][2]`.

Try this :

```
Celebrity = {"first_name": "Mariah", "last_name": "Carey", "birth_date": "27.03.1970", "hobbies": ["sing", "compose", "act"]}
user_input = input ("Please enter a number between 1 and 8: ")

if int(user_input) == 2:
    print(Celebrity["birth_date"][4:5])

if int(user_input) == 4:
    print (Celebrity["hobbies"][2])
```

Output :

```
Please enter a number between 1 and 8: 2
3

Please enter a number between 1 and 8: 4
act
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to get value you need to use key in square brackets. If you want get only mount you can get value by index. And if you want get last value in array you can use index `-1` like this `Celebrity["hobbies"][-1]`

```
Celebrity = {"first_name": "Mariah", "last_name": "Carey", "birth_date": "27.03.1970", "hobbies": ["sing", "compose", "act"]}

user_input = input ("Please enter a number between 1 and 8: ")

if int(user_input) == 2:
    print(Celebrity["birth_date"][4])

if int(user_input) == 4:
    print (Celebrity["hobbies"][-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go;

```
Celebrity = {"first_name": "Mariah", "last_name": "Carey", "birth_date": "27.03.1970", "hobbies": ["sing", "compose", "act"]}


user_input = input ("Please enter a number between 1 and 8: ")


if int(user_input) == 2:
print(Celebrity["birth_date"][4:5])

if int(user_input) == 4:
print (Celebrity["hobbies"][2])
```

You were placing brackets on the wrong spots, which were then getting "h" and "b" from "birth_date" and "hobbies" as keys.